# Is it natural to say "Turn the bike so that you and it are side by side"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Looking at the above picture, I am sure we can say "**the woman is sitting on a chair and there is another  chair *opposite* the woman**"

Now:

[image]

...

[image]

You were sitting at a table.

Your child parked the bike like the 1st picture in which the head of the bike is pointing to your side.

Now, I want to ask the child to turn the bike so that it looks like the picture 2.

Is it natural to say "**Turn the bike so that you and it are side by side**" in that situation because some children don't know how to put things in a neat way?

Comment: A bike has [handlebars](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/handlebars). If 'you' is the parent, you haven't said where the child is - but a native speaker might say something like "Turn the bike _this_ way round". indicating with a gesture what they meant.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly neat about either position of the bike.  Now I can imagine that in the first picture the bike may be blocking a walkway that goes alongside the table.  So you might say to the child "Your bike is blocking the path" or "Don't block the path with the bike", or perhaps "turn your bike so it doesn't block the path".  Perhaps you don't like the way that the bike sticks out.  So "Don't leave your bike sticking out like that." The trouble in answering the question is not that there is no answer, but rather there are many.